# How to grant a folder with write permissions for installing gems in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation

the biggest problem I have with installing anything on my computer related to Ruby and Rails, is not having 'write' permissions to a specific folder.

**For example:** "You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory"

Instead of always using Sudo command, which sometimes doesn't solve the problem, how can I give myself 'write' permissions?

Comment: [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)?

Comment: You could use `rvm` or just run `sudo chown ... ` to Gems directory, or `chmod ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo chmod 777 directory_name
```

It grants all permissions to the user.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `chmod 777`, especially on the directory where third parties code will be stored (in case of @JoshZandman it's a ruby gems directory).

You should better consider using at least 755 (full permissions for the owner and read and execute permission for others) or `chown user:group` on that directory.